# Typed selectList in myBatis

Tags: java, ibatis, mybatis

I'm migrating from iBatis to myBatis and I'm facing this issue: when I call the selectList method it returns a `List<Object>` instead of the correct type (e.g. `List<Document>` ) so I get an error here:

```
return createFiscalCodesMap(getSqlSession().selectList(STMT_LOAD, parameters));

private Map<String, String> createFiscalCodesMap(List<Document> documentList) { ... }
```

This is the xml element involved:

```
<select id="load" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultType="Document">...</select>
```

I've read the selectList returns a typed list (`List<E>`) but I can't figure out how to get it.

PS: I'm writing code to migrate to myBatis automatically, so I need a way to solve the problem without changing a lot of things.

**EDIT**: 
I'm trying different solutions and I can't figure out where is the problem.

This doesn't work (error: Cannot cast from `List<Object>` to `List<Document>`):

```
return createFiscalCodesMap((List<Document>) getSqlSession().selectList(STMT_LOAD, parameters));
```

This works:

```
List<Document> temp = getSqlSession().selectList(STMT_LOAD, parameters);
return createFiscalCodesMap(temp);
```

Comment: I've got the problem.
selectList is defined in this way
    <E> List<E> selectList(String statement, Object parameter);

so get the type using the assignment

Answer (score 1):

As the selectList method is defined with generics in mind, and you are not using generics for the method call, it is normal to have a List of Objects returned.

The correct way to avoid the error should be invoking selectList with generics:

```
return createFiscalCodesMap(getSqlSession().<Document>selectList(STMT_LOAD, parameters));
```

Please note that selectList with generics is supported since MyBatis 3.1.0, so make sure you are using 3.1.0+ to make this work.